# Date time format in oracle sql and conversion and comparison

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures, comparison, procedure

I have a column xyz in nvarchar2 in my oracle table. I am setting a date into it from my java file with in '"yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss"' format. Now i have created a procedure in oracle sql, in that procedure i have fetched xyz into a variable 'time_new'. I want to compare my variable with 120 hours in an if block. how can I make this comparison in my plsql procedure 'if block' ?

Answer (score 0):

declare the variable time_new as the date.

assign it a value using `to_date` as follows:

```
time_new := to_date(Xyz, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss')
```

Now, you can compare it with any dates.

As described in the comment, you want to check if the difference of dates is less or greater than 120 then you can use the following:

```
IF SYSDATE + 120/24 > time_new --something like this
```

Comment: i need to compare the date fetched in time_new with current sysdate and check whether the difference is less than or greater than 120 hours

Comment: sysdate + '120' HOURS is not being accepted by oracle

Comment: Yes, @VrindaGoel you are right, Updated the answer. But interestingly, Oracle will not even give you an error if you do `sysdate + '120' HOURS`. the result will be addition of 120 days. Interesting!!